# Is there a way to do a java class variable for structs in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct that needs to keep track of how many instances of this struct there are. Is there any way to do it within the struct, or do I have to make a separate counter outside the struct and increment this?

Thanks

Comment: The former, you need to do it externally.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need a `static` variable but in C a `struct` is not allowed to have `static` variables (while in C++ you can, since they're basically classes). Especially because there are no namespaces so it wouldn't make any difference to have it declared inside a `struct` definition.

You are allowed to have global `static` variables though, which could be the simpler solution if you don't want to expose anything, something like:

```
//header.h

void incrementCounter();
void decrementCount();
int counterValue();

//header.c

static int counter = 0;

void incrementCounter() { ++counter; }

..
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the C language keeps track of when structures are created and destroyed.  Indeed, when functions like malloc() are used to reserve memory for structures, the compiler has no way of knowing what structures "exist".  This is different from Java or C++, where the only way an object can come into existence is by asking the code for the object to create an instance.  Incidentally, in .NET, class objects are generally only brought into existence via request to the underlying class, but structures--as in C--can be brought into existence without any of the code associated with the structure knowing about it.